# What is the distance in between two shells of a spherical capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy, capacitance

I am studying Capacitance for my Physics class. We have been working with parallel-plate capacitors, which I understand perfectly. However, I’ve seen some exercises with spherical and cylindrical capacitors. In them, I have learned to calculate the capacitance by simply applying the definition, but I am having trouble deriving the maximum potential difference and maximum potential energy that can be present before dielectric breakdown. Can you please explain this to me? I really want to understand these concepts, as I do for the parallel-plate capacitor.

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At which surface is the electric field (potential gradient) the largest?

[image]

That is where electrical breakdown is most likely to happen.

From that you can find the potential at that surface and hence the required potential difference.

Comment: It’s at the surface of the inner sphere, right? So then I can use the definition of capacitance (having calculated the maximum charge from the field) to get the maximum potential?